# Wrong autoref names when using polyglossia and 'english' env

Tags: hyperref, luatex, polyglossia, autoref

Related:

- [Wrong autoref names when using babel's `main=` feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257339/wrong-autoref-names-when-using-babels-main-feature)
- [Hyperref ignores \setdefaultlanguage from polyglossia](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21255/hyperref-ignores-setdefaultlanguage-from-polyglossia)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{Demo}
    \label{fig:demo}
  \end{figure}

  \begin{english}
    \autoref{fig:demo}
  \end{english}

  \begin{spanish}
    \autoref{fig:demo}
  \end{spanish}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE image: both references are in English, though Spanish is the main language]

I tried the `babel` macro, but it does not work; adding `spanish` to `hyperref`'s loading options just changes the problem language.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you also note that `\usepackage[spanish]{hyperref}` should be loaded after your `\setdefaultlanguage` etc. commands?

Comment: Nope, but it gives the same result (both refs are in Spanish).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add a redefinition of `\figureautorefname` for Spanish, but also to change it in `\blockextras@english`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\appto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Figura}}
\makeatletter
\appto\blockextras@english{\renewcommand\figureautorefname{Figure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Demo}
\label{fig:demo}
\end{figure}

\begin{english}
\autoref{fig:demo}
\end{english}

\begin{spanish}
\autoref{fig:demo}
\end{spanish}

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, `cleveref` works out of the box.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}

\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage[variant=british]{english}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Demo}
\label{fig:demo}
\end{figure}

\begin{english}
\Cref{fig:demo}
\end{english}

\begin{spanish}
\Cref{fig:demo}
\end{spanish}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The first method works like a charme, while I could not compile the second solution, seems that `cleveref` is breaking something.

Comment: @mmj Works for me even with TL2020/pretest. Please make a minimal example and open a new question.

Comment: I could not compile with XeLaTeX your exact second solution neither on my MikTeX-TeXworks system (updated a few days ago) nor on Overleaf.

Comment: @mmj You're right. The people at `polyglossia` seem to have broken compatibility with `cleveref`. :-(

Comment: @mmj Specify the main language: `\usepackage[spanish]{cleveref}`

Comment: With specification of main language when `cleveref` package loads, the second MWE solution works well, but not in my real world complex document; the references of secondary languare are wrong. I'll go with the first solution which always works well. Thanks fot it.