# Change autoref language?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, babel, languages

I am trying to use latex to write something in polish. I am using `babel` package together with `hyperref`. I thought this would be enough, but apparently it is not.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}
\label{sec:here}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:here} This is a figure caption}
\end{figure}

\autoref{sec:here}

\autoref{fig:here}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: output]

As you can see the figure caption is correctly written in Polish, but the autoreferences are still in English.

I guess it should be something simple. For example, the question [Wrong autoref names when using babel's `main=` feature](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257339/wrong-autoref-names-when-using-babels-main-feature) suggests that the above *should* work.
All other material I was able to find on stackexchange or google was focusing on more specific uses than the one I am describing.

So, what am I missing?

A possible walkaround I am aware of is to manually define all those names through `\def\figureautorefname`, but I hope someone already did that in a public package and is properly maintained.

Comment: As far as I can see in the `hyperref.sty` (TeXlive 2016), there's no Polish translation for the autoref names. So, you'll have to introduce them yourself.

Comment: You could post your adjustments on this question as an answer after you done them for future readers.

Comment: You have to do `\renewcommand{\chapterautorefname}{....}` etc with the relevant Polish names

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, support for `Polish` language is not defined in `hyperref` for the `\...autorefname` macros.

`hyperref` supports `english,afrikaans,french,german,spanish,catalan,portuges,magyar, russian,italian,vietnamese` yet, as of version 6.85a from 2017/03/14.

A trial of a solution:

The macro

`\ProvidePolishAutoRefNames{figure=\figurename,chapter,section={PolishSectionName},table,equation={PolishEquationName}}`

loops through the counter names that are given in a comma separated list and generates the `\##1autorefname` on the fly.

If `figure=\figurename` is given, it uses the name from `\figurename` etc, if just the counter name `X` is given, it tries to use `\Xname`, which is not defined in any case.

Since I don't speak Polish, I have used `PolishSectionName` etc. as replacement.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_gset:cpn {cpx,cpo}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ProvidePolishAutoRefNames}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {% Loop through names
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {=} {##1}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1} autorefname}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq } > {1} {% Check whether there is a "=", if so, use the RHS 
      \cs_gset:cpx {\l_tmpa_tl} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
    }{% No, try to evaluate \##1name, e.g. \chaptername
      \cs_gset:cpx {\l_tmpa_tl} {\use:c{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}name}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}

\addto\captionspolish{%
  \ProvidePolishAutoRefNames{figure=\figurename,chapter,section={PolishSectionName},table,equation={PolishEquationName}}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo chapter}\label{foochapter}



\section{foo}

\figureautorefname

\label{sec:here}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:here} This is a figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation} 
  E=mc^{2} \label{fooequation}
\end{equation}

See \autoref{foochapter} or \autoref{fooequation}

\autoref{sec:here}

\autoref{fig:here}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar version, by defining `\HyLang@polish` analogously to `HyLang@french` etc.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_gset:cpn {cpx,cpo}
\NewDocumentCommand{\ProvidePolishAutoRefNames}{m}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {% Loop through names
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpb_seq {=} {##1}
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1} autorefname}
    \int_compare:nNnTF {\seq_count:N \l_tmpb_seq } > {1} {% Check whether there is a "=", if so, use the RHS 
      \cs_gset:cpx {\l_tmpa_tl} {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
    }{% No, try to evaluate \##1name, e.g. \chaptername
      \cs_gset:cpx {\l_tmpa_tl} {\use:c{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}name}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{hyperref}


\makeatletter
\def\HyLang@polish{
  \ProvidePolishAutoRefNames{figure=\figurename,chapter,section={PolishSectionName},table,equation={PolishEquationName}}
}

\HyLang@DeclareLang{polish}{polish}{}

\makeatother



\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo chapter}\label{foochapter}



\section{foo}

\figureautorefname

\label{sec:here}

\begin{figure}
\caption{\label{fig:here} This is a figure caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation} 
  E=mc^{2} \label{fooequation}
\end{equation}

See \autoref{foochapter} or \autoref{fooequation}

\autoref{sec:here}

\autoref{fig:here}
\end{document}
```